# Logging from EJB module in JavaEE, maven configuration

Tags: logging, ejb, maven, java-ee-6

I have tried for hours to get my project working but the EJB part is still failing with a *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory* (I want to output some log in my EJB).

The layout of the project is the following:

```
|-- nnWeb-ear
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       `-- main
|           |-- application
|           |   `-- META-INF
|           |       `-- MANIFEST.MF
|           `-- java
|-- nnWeb-ejb
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |   `-- com
|       |   |       `-- test
|       |   |           `-- packaging
|       |   |               `-- SimpleStateLess.java
|       |   `-- resources
|       |       |-- logback.xml
|       |       `-- META-INF
|       |           `-- MANIFEST.MF
|       `-- test
|           `-- java
|               `-- com
|                   `-- test
|                       `-- packaging
|-- nnWeb-web
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |   `-- com
|       |   |       `-- test
|       |   |           `-- packaging
|       |   |               |-- SimpleEJB.java
|       |   |               `-- SimpleServlet.java
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   |   `-- logback.xml
|       |   `-- webapp
|       |       |-- index.jsp
|       |       `-- WEB-INF
|       |           `-- sun-web.xml
|       `-- test
|           `-- java
`-- pom.xml
```

the main pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
  <artifactId>nnWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>nnWeb</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <modules>
    <module>nnWeb-ear</module>
    <module>nnWeb-web</module>
    <module>nnWeb-ejb</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

The ejb pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>nnWeb</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
    <artifactId>nnWeb-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>nnWebEjb</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Java.Net Maven2 Repository, hosts the javaee-api dependency</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>APP-INF/lib</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>nnWeb-ejb</finalName>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>endorsed</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- javaee6 contains upgrades of APIs contained within the JDK itself.
                                 As such these need to be placed on the bootclasspath, rather than classpath of the
                                 compiler.
                                 If you don't make use of these new updated API, you can delete the profile.
                                 On non-SUN jdk, you will need to create a similar profile for your jdk, with the similar property as sun.boot.class.path in Sun's JDK.-->
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar${path.separator}${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
</project>
```

The ear pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>nnWeb</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
    <artifactId>nnWeb-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>nnWebEar</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                   <!-- <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        </archive>-->
                        <defaultJavaBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>

                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>nnWeb-ear</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>nnWeb-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.packaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>nnWeb-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.sli4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>sli4j-slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
</project>
```

and the SimpleStateless.java EJB:

```
package com.test.packaging;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Stateless
public class SimpleStateLess {
     private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleStateLess.class);

   public void constructLog(){
       logger.debug("Finally got logging working in ejb module :)");
   }
}
```

Once packaged, the ear file looks like:

```
|-- APP-INF
|   `-- lib
|       |-- aopalliance-1.0.jar
|       |-- guice-2.0.jar
|       |-- logback-classic-0.9.18.jar
|       |-- logback-core-0.9.18.jar
|       |-- slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
|       |-- slf4j-jdk14-1.5.10.jar
|       |-- sli4j-core-2.0.jar
|       `-- sli4j-slf4j-jdk14-2.0.jar
|-- META-INF
|   |-- application.xml
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- maven
|       `-- com.test.packaging
|           `-- nnWeb-ear
|               |-- pom.properties
|               `-- pom.xml
|-- ngWeb-web.war
`-- nnWeb-ejb.jar
```

and the ejb.jar manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: dev
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_21
Class-Path: APP-INF/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar APP-INF/lib/logback
 -core-0.9.18.jar APP-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
```

Note that logging from the war package works (Servlet logging + EJB logging using the WEB-INF/lib directory) and according to what I found, logging in the EJB should work when deploying the ear (if the manifest is correct).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the exploded `ear` packaging and the `ejb.jar` manifest,

`nnWeb-ejb.jar` is in the same hierarchy as `APP-INF`.

Thus the following `Class-Path` entries become invalid...

```
Class-Path: APP-INF/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar APP-INF/lib/logback
 -core-0.9.18.jar APP-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
```

They would need to be

```
Class-Path: ../APP-INF/lib/logback-classic-0.9.18.jar ../APP-INF/lib/logback
 -core-0.9.18.jar ../APP-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, after updating the Manifest, the problem is still there. Just in case, I made an archive of the "dummy" project : http://rapidshare.com/files/425732230/EJBLogging.tar.gz

Comment: Finally got the solution, you were almost right about the wrong classpath. Changing   the ear pom entry to <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir> and the ejb entry to                            <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix> did the trick. As often, a big coffee helps finding the solution :)